# Pacific-centric Robinson projection with ggplot in R

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, map-projections

I'm trying to create a pacific-centric Robinson projection in R with ggplot...

converting a shapefile to a Robinson CRS using `spTransform` and setting longitude to 150 degrees doesn't work, and `fortify` errors out.

like this:

```
world_robin <- spTransform(world2, CRS("+proj=robin +lon_0=150 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
plot(world_robin, col = "khaki", bg = "azure2")
```

And there doesn't appear to be a way to do it later in the process when setting a projection for ggmap: 
ie,

```
coord_map("mollweide", orientation=c(90, 0, 150))
```

this appears to be the best, but it's not quite there.

Comment: p.s. I'm using a  1:110m shapefile from Natural Earth.

Comment: You can edit the question instead of adding it to the comments.

Comment: Anyone with this same question, I recommend checking out this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77944263/1681480) using the latest `sf`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need GDAL / `rgdal` for this and it's 180 vs 150 but you should be able to extrapolate. GIS SO FTW!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

# assumes you are in the ne_110m... directory
# split the world and stitch it back together again

system("ogr2ogr world_part1.shp ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp -clipsrc -180 -90 0 90")
system("ogr2ogr world_part2.shp ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp -clipsrc 0 -90 180 90")
system('ogr2ogr world_part1_shifted.shp world_part1.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry,360,0), admin FROM world_part1"')
system("ogr2ogr world_0_360_raw.shp world_part2.shp")
system("ogr2ogr -update -append world_0_360_raw.shp world_part1_shifted.shp -nln world_0_360_raw")

world <- readOGR("ne_110m_admin_0_countries/world_0_360_raw.shp", "world_0_360_raw")
world_robin <- spTransform(world, CRS("+proj=robin +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

world_dat <- fortify(world_robin)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world_dat, map=world_dat,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="khaki", color="black", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="azure2"))
gg
```

[image]

You can use `gdalUtils` for this as well, but it just calls the system binaries and you have to specify the clipping polygons with well known strings (so the `system` call is a few characters shorter for the line).

FYI: Doing this means you have to shift and project *all* points/shapes before plotting with ggplot2.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much.