# st_crop on pacific centred naturalearth world map

Tags: ggplot2, maps, r-sf

Im trying to crop a pacific centred world map using the naturalearth maps data as an sf object. The map was created following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146735/visual-bug-when-changing-robinson-projections-central-meridian-with-ggplot2) and the following code:

```
worldMap <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_make_valid()

target_crs <- st_crs("+proj=eqc +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=133")

# define a long & slim polygon that overlaps the meridian line & set its CRS to match
# that of world
# Centered in lon 133

offset <- 180 - 133


polygon <- st_polygon(x = list(rbind(
  c(-0.0001 - offset, 90),
  c(0 - offset, 90),
  c(0 - offset, -90),
  c(-0.0001 - offset, -90),
  c(-0.0001 - offset, 90)
))) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)


# modify world dataset to remove overlapping portions with world's polygons
world2 <- worldMap %>% st_difference(polygon)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

# Transform
world3 <- world2 %>% st_transform(crs = target_crs)

ggplot(data = world3, aes(group = admin)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey")
```

[image: pacific centered map]

I would like to crop to an area of interest covering the Indian and Pacific Oceans (like this screenshot taken from the "maps" world2 projection):

[image: desired crop extent]

To crop, I tried the following:

```
world4 <- st_crop(world3, c(xmin= 30, ymin = -40, xmax = 230, ymax = 40))
```

However, the code above produces the incorrect crop with crazy small lat/long increments:

```
ggplot(data = world3, aes(group = admin)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey")
```

[image: too small?!]

If anyone can help me to figure out how to crop using lat and long to define the area for this pacific centred map it would be greatly apriciated. I know that there are other ways to obtain a pacific centred map but the future planned analysis for this project requires it to be an rnaturalearth map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to define the bbox for the crop filter using the same CRS as the `world3` object. For example:

```r
world4 <- st_crop(
  x = world3, 
  y = st_as_sfc(
    st_bbox(c(xmin= 30, ymin = -40, xmax = 230, ymax = 40), crs = 4326)
  ) %>% st_transform(target_crs)
)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
ggplot(data = world4, aes(group = admin)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @agila! Embarrassed I missed that!